# Find last child of Row that fits screen

Tags: flutter

Here is what I am trying to build:

[image]

I have a list of elements that I would like to show as widgets that are horizontally aligned.

But instead of using a scrollview I just want to display the last widget as one that indicates that there are more elements that won't fit.

Obviously if the device rotates from portrait to landscape the list should adjust dynamically (displaying more items).

Help is highly appreciated.